# Determine if it is multiple I'm solving an exercise that says, of 2 numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm solving an exercise that says:

> It can be determined that (A + B) is a multiple of 7, if it is known
> that:
>
> (1) A is a multiple of 4 and B is a multiple of 3
>
> (2) The difference between A and B is a multiple of 7.

I know that,

An number `A` is multiple of another number `B`, when:

`A = kB`, where `k` is an integer.

Then I solved it:

[Image of my development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngv0r.jpg)

I thought that was fine, but the answer is "Additional information is required", then could you tell me what, I was wrong?

Comment: Are (1) and (2) separate question constraints, or do both apply at the same time? And are there more constraints? If not, consider $A=32, B=18$.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is indeed $4$ multiplied by some integer, and $B$ is $3$ multiplied by some integer, but it doesn't have to be the *same* integer. So $A+B$ isn't $4K+3K$, but rather $4K+3L$.

Answer (score 1):

From the fact that $A$ is a multiple of $4$ and that $B$ is a multiple of $3$, you deduce that there are natural numbers $k$ and $k'$ such that $A=4k$ and that $B=3k'$. Your error was that you assumed that $k=k'$.

Take, for instance, the case in which $A=24$ and $=3$. Then $A$ is a multiple of $4$, $B$ is a multiple of $3$, $A-B$ is a multiple of $7$, but $A+B$ isn't a multiple of $7$.

Answer (score 0):

First consider B being a multiple of 7.  If so, then for A+B to be a multiple of 7, A must also be a multiple of 7.  Therefore one set of valid pairs for (A, B) is (28a, 21b); a,b are integers.

Next consider B, not a multiple of 7.  If so, then for A+B to be a multiple of 7, A cannot be a multiple of 7 either.  Now, if either A+B or A-B is a multiple of 7, the other cannot be because the difference between them is 2B, which cannot be a multiple of 7.

Only valid pairs are therefore (28a, 21b); a,b are integers.  So, you also need to know that either A or B is a multiple of 7.